# mismatch importing a mysqldump file

Tags: mysql

I have been trying to import a mysqldump file but I get a mismatch on the inserts.

The mysqldump file has this inserts:

```
    INSERT INTO `venues` VALUES (...);
```

But sometimes the values are inserted in other columns that do not correspond.

If I specify the columns names in the inserts to be:

```
    INSERT INTO `venues` (column_one, column_two, ...) VALUES (...)
```

Then the values are inserted in correct order, why is this? how can I insert large amounts of data in order without specifying the column names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your dump file and your table don't have matching columns then you have some choices:

1. Edit the dumpfile and fix the insert statement so it aligns with what you have
2. Import the data as-is into a secondary table. Then do an `insert select` to copy the data from the temp table into the main table. Specify the appropriate (matching) column names.

**Edit:** I suppose a third option would be to redump the data in such a manner that the column names were included in the `insert` statements.

Comment: Whats the command to "redump the data in such a manner that the column names were included in the insert statements." ?

Comment: IIRC mysqldump has an option for that.